# AT+CMGR Command Error - Receiving two numbers

Tags: ip, gsm, at-command, gprs, telit

whenever I try to read Inbox Message using GSM Module (AT+CMGR), I'm getting two phone numbers instead of one that too some unknown numbers, any idea why…?

And non of these phone numbers are familiar to me, some random numbers appear every time I try to read inbox messages using AT command "AT+CMGR"

```
/* Read the message which will change the status of the message */
[2023-06-02 15:07:25:175_S:] AT+CMGR=2
[2023-06-02 15:07:25:251_R:] AT+CMGR=2
[2023-06-02 15:07:25:523_R:] 
[2023-06-02 15:07:25:534_R:] +CMGR: "REC UNREAD","+9189******87",,"23/06/02,15:07:16+22",145,4,0,0,"*+9170******00*",145,8
```